# Electrochemical cell polarity and electrodes

Tags: electrochemistry

In an electrochemical cell, the anode undergoes oxidation and the cathode undergoes reduction. This means that the anode *loses* electrons while the cathode *gains* electrons.

However, the anode is negatively-charged while the cathode is positively-charged. Why is this so?

Answer (score 5):

The electrons which are "given up" by the oxidized species at the [anode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anode) flow from the anode through the electric circuit to the [cathode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode), where they are "needed" for the reduction reaction. The oxidation creates an excess of electrons (negative charge) at the anode, which is compensated by the consumption of electrons at the electron-deficient cathode (positive charge) for the reduction reaction. In summary, the flow of electrons in the electrochemical cell is from anode (electron source) to cathode (electron drain).

Comment: So when the anode is said to be 'negatively-charged'  it implies that the anode has an excess of electrons which are available for donation to the cathode?

Comment: Yes, the excess electrons from the oxidation reaction are available for the reduction reaction at the cathode.

Answer (score 0):

Oxidized species give up electrons to an electron pool which prior to their flow to the other half cell create a large negative charge on the electrode where oxidation takes place.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you have questions about how our site works, please consider taking the [tour] and visiting our [help]. This answer does not provide any additional information over the previous answer. Do you have more that you could add to make your answer distinct?